# WhyContentControl hides some functionality of Label in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am beginner to WPF. Below is my View code in WPF. If I run the exact code my Label 'Error_Label' gets hidden at run time or gives no effect.Also GridView stops reflecting my data. But if I remove just 3 tags ContentControl, ContentControl.ContentTemplate,DataTemplate with Triggers it works properly. May I know the reason behind this?

**Not-Working Version**

```
<Window x:Class="Seris.VehicalForm"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="600">
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10 " >
                <Label Content="Vehical No" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBox Name="VehicalNo_Text" Height="23" Width="80" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding VehicalNo}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <Label Content="Model" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBox Name="Model_Text" Height="23" Width="80" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Model}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <Label Content="Manufacturing Date" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <DatePicker Name="ManufacturingDate_DateTime" SelectedDate="{Binding ManufacturingDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <Label Content="IU No" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBox Height="23" Width="80" Name="IUNO_Text" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding IUNo}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <Label Content="Personnel" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <ComboBox Name="Personnel_Combo" Text="{Binding Personnel}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="116"/>
                <Separator Height="20" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="16"/>
                <Button Name="Save_Button" Command="{Binding SaveButton_Command}" Content="Save" Width="66"/>
                <Label x:Name="Error_Label" Content="{Binding ErrorMessage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="41" Width="137"/>
                <ListView  Name ="Grid" Height="294" Width="371" ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Vehical No" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding VehicalNo}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Model" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Model}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="ManufacturingDate" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ManufacturingDate}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="IUNo" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IUNo}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Personnel" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Personnel}" />
                        </GridView>
                   </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
                <Label Name="Notification"/>
            </WrapPanel>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocused, ElementName=Grid}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Content" TargetName="Notification">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}Name is '{0}'}">
                                           <Binding ElementName="Notification" Path="Text" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
</Window>
```

**Working Version**

```
<Window x:Class="Seris.VehicalForm"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="600">

            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10 " >
                <Label Content="Vehical No" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBox Name="VehicalNo_Text" Height="23" Width="80" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding VehicalNo}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <Label Content="Model" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBox Name="Model_Text" Height="23" Width="80" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Model}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <Label Content="Manufacturing Date" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <DatePicker Name="ManufacturingDate_DateTime" SelectedDate="{Binding ManufacturingDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <Label Content="IU No" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBox Height="23" Width="80" Name="IUNO_Text" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding IUNo}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <Label Content="Personnel" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <ComboBox Name="Personnel_Combo" Text="{Binding Personnel}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="116"/>
                <Separator Height="20" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="16"/>
                <Button Name="Save_Button" Command="{Binding SaveButton_Command}" Content="Save" Width="66"/>
                <Label x:Name="Error_Label" Content="{Binding ErrorMessage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="41" Width="137"/>
                <ListView  Name ="Grid" Height="294" Width="371" ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Vehical No" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding VehicalNo}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Model" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Model}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="ManufacturingDate" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ManufacturingDate}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="IUNo" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IUNo}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Personnel" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Personnel}" />
                        </GridView>
                   </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
                <Label Name="Notification"/>
            </WrapPanel>

</Window>
```

Comment: Unclear. make 2 shorter versions, 1 working and 1 not. And always explain 'stops working'.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I updated. Kindly check.

Comment: it seems error in datatrigger try this http://prntscr.com/48unwa

Comment: @HeenaPatil Triggers works completely perfect if they are run separately. SO no issue with Data Trigger.

Comment: SaveButton_Command itself is not firing, neither Error_Label is working.

Comment: @HeenaPatil: Even I tried according to your link also. That also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems error in **Datatrigger**

```
 <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocused, ElementName=Grid}" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="Content" TargetName="Notification" Value="{Binding Path=Text,StringFormat={},Name is'{0}'}"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```